# Как грамотно сформировать архитектуру чат-бота?

Tags: python, telegram, архитектура, бот

Имеется задача написать относительно непростого чат-бота с большим функционалом для телеграма.
Я использую *pyTelegramBotAPI*, где для обработки событий используются конструкции вида:

```py
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Привет")
```

В большей части туториалов и документации используются простые примеры, где такие хендлеры просто друг за другом идут в одном файле.
Но бот не будет обрабатывать парочку команд, выдавая заранее заготовленные ответы, поэтому если все делать так, как описано выше, выйдет миллион инструкций в ряд в одном файле, что, я считаю, не есть хорошо.

Возможно есть какие либо варианты организовать это дело более красиво и грамотно?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Ну, спрячьте логику, если она у вас большая, в какие-то классы, которые будете подключать в бота и вызывать. Или у вас планируется миллион команд боту и в этом проблема?

Comment: Архитектура пляшет от функционала. ТЗ разбираете на крупные куски... Архитектор уже должен владеть декомпозицией... )

Comment: CrazyElf, не то что бы команд, но да, планируется что он будет обрабатывать множество событий (сообщения, нажатия кнопок, команды в том числе)

Comment: Вот... выделите файлы для соответствующих классов - сообщения, кнопки, команды...

Comment: Но это одна сторона медали... С другой стороны рассмотрите функционал, как среду пользователя. Например; блок приветствия и приема, от него блок обработки желания клиента и блок справки для клиента... и так далее. В общем рисуйте блоки на листе и стрелочками соединяйте...